# How to record video via react-native and upload to server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, video-streaming, rtmp

I have react-native and redux on front, and nginx, nodejs/express in back-end side associated with mongodb database.Is there any possible way to record video from react-native and store it in back-end storage via nginx rtmp module.Thank you!!!!!

Comment: it looks like you can record video using `react-native-camera` and then you can access the file and upload after: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

Comment: yes current time I'm using react-native-camera for recording video but after recording uploading in server takes long time.I want to ulpoad video with separated chunks and upload them via rtmp.